# How to fix ng-pattern in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have this textbox and it shoud be red until user enter all 5 characters but and then should be green but i get green when user enter first character and its not even need to be number...so how can i fix that?

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ZipCode, new { id = "zip", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "5", @required = "required", ng_model = "zipCode", ng_pattern = @"^[0-9]{5}$" })
```

and style

```
.ng-invalid {
    background-color:#FF8080;

}
.ng-valid {
    background-color:#ADEBAD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your pattern like to read like this: `/^(\w{1,5})$/`

\w is short for all alphanumeric chars and the anchors force the pattern to match entire input.

My JS looks like this:

```
    var App = angular.module('App',[]).controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);

    function Ctrl($scope){
      $scope.noLetters5LengthRegex = /^\d{1,5}$/;
    }
```

My Markup:

```
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="something" ng-pattern="noLetters5LengthRegex"
   required/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: You can take the pattern out of the controller function and place it into the view directly if you would like, its the same thing just a matter of where you want it more.

Here is a working demo for you:

**UPDATED AS PER OP REQUEST**

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/QbaxrE

Comment: i tried your pattern but i need to enter more then 5 to get valid pattern

Comment: Working fine over here for me, enter 1 2 3 4 5 if you enter a 1 2 3 4 5 a or 1 1 2 3 4 5 it wont work, if you enter 1 2 3 4 it wont work . must be 5 digits, no exceptions. Please tell me how it is not working

Comment: because i need to enter digits and i want any character to enter and must be more then 5 characters...because its pattern for password

Comment: I will modify my patten to fit but you didnt ask this in your original question, you included the [0-9] sequence which led me and others to think you only wanted digits. Here is your updated pattern: /^(\w{1,5})$/

Answer (score 0):

Your range needs to have a comma.

```
ng_pattern = @"^[0-9]{5,5}$"
```

I would suggest what Alpha G33k has said and use the digit shorthand as well since it makes it more readable.

```
ng_pattern = @"^\d{5,}$"
```

And if you want 5 and only 5 characters, your pattern needs to be the following:

```
ng_pattern = @"^\d{5,5}$"
```

Comment: when i use this only works if i start with numbers but if i start with letters then i need more then 5 characters

Comment: Can you describe the exact pattern that you're looking for? For example, you need to have a word that can contain or begin with letter characters but ends with 5  digits?

Comment: its for password...so user can enter all possible characters but it must be more then 5...so it can start with letter or number or _ ,- all possible but it must have more then 5 and less then 16

Comment: based on that, you could do

^(\w|\d){5,16}$

This will allow you to enter in 5-16 alphanumeric characters and the underscore (_).

But the only requirement is that it must be between 5 and 16 characters in length. With this regex, you can enter in all characters, all underscores and all digits. 

You might want to take a look at a regex for passwords like the link below and modify it to fit your requirements

http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/